# Converting a list to double quoted comma separated strings

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a problem I can't seem able to fix by myself, nor by searching the internets.

I have a list, stored in a file, like this:

```
apple
banana
pineapple
```

And I would like each string to be in double quote, and comma separated, like this:

```
"apple","banana","pineapple"
```

Ideally, the last word of the list shouldn't have a comma after it, but this is not mandatory.

The idea behind this is to be able to create a JSON formatted document populated by a list of item stored in a plain text file.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk -v RS='' -v OFS='","' 'NF { $1 = $1; print "\"" $0 "\"" }' file
```

Output:

```
"apple","banana","pineapple"
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot! I've tried something similar from another thread here, but couldn't get it working. Your solution just works perfectly.

Comment: @Nesousx I added a minor tweak just to make sure there are indeed fields around. You're welcome :)

Comment: What does `$1 =$1` do ?

Comment: @Jidder Sometimes $0 doesn't get itself updated with OFS so you alter a part of it just perhaps to activate the `changed` flag in Awk's implementation.

Comment: Also FS gets set to `\n` when setting `RS=''` so you could remove it :)

Comment: Yeah I had tested removing FS and it worked but I wasn't sure if it was the general behaviour.

Comment: Verification. It explains it at the bottom of this page https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html. Pretty sure GNU is correct

Comment: @Jidder I know but I'm concerned about other Awk too. Anyway I test it in some others so I guess I'd just remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Perl also deserves a mention:

```
perl -lne 'push @a, qq("$_") }{ print join(",", @a)' file
```

Builds an array `@a` containing the value on each line, wrapped in double quotes. Then once the file has been processed, prints out a comma separated list of all the elements in `@a`.

The so-called [eskimo greeting `}{`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Eskimo_greeting) is a shorthand used to create an `END` block, due to the way that the `-n` and `-p` switches are implemented.

Output:

```
"apple","banana","pineapple"
```

If it's JSON you're looking for, you could use `encode_json`:

```
perl -MJSON -lne 'push @a, $_ }{ print encode_json(\@a)' file
```

This turns the array into a real JSON-encoded list:

```
["apple","banana","pineapple"]
```

Comment: `}{` is an amusing trick, but it should be clarified for the benefit of newbie readers that it's just a side-effect of `-p` wrapping the expression in `{ }`, not some sort of a keyword in and of itself

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this method:

```
sed -r ':loop ; N ; s/\n/,/g ; $s/[^,]+/"&"/g ; t loop' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` and `paste` solution:

```
sed -e 's/^\|$/"/g' file | paste -s -d, -
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk`

```
awk '{printf "\"%s\"",$1}' file | awk '{gsub(/""/,"\",\"")}1'
"apple","banana","pineapple"
```

or

```
awk '{printf "\"%s\"",$1}' file | sed 's/""/","/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

No fancy stuff awk:

```
awk 'x{x=x","}{x=x"\""$1"\""}END{print x}' file
```

Explained version:

```
awk '
  out { out = out "," }           # if there is already something in the output string, append a comma to it
      { out = out "\"" $1 "\"" }  # always append the quoted first column of input to the output string
  END { print out }               # finally, print the output string
' file
```

The peculiar ordering of the first two lines matters - it prevents the final comma from being appended.